# grep search pattern from file containing list of patterns, write result of each pattern to individual files

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I have a directory containing daily cds for the month. I need to search all cds for a list of ph numbers and write result to individual files for each pattern.

Currently I'm using the below command manually for each ph number in the dir containing monthly cds and writing the result of each number to individual file.

```
grep -rn 111222333 /dir-containing-new-indivdual-logs/111222333.csv
```

I tried adding `grep -f` option to specify search list but no luck as my syntax for the entire command is wrong.

Comment: If you want to use `grep`, but write to individual files, you need to loop over the `grep`, for example a `while` loop `read`ing from the ph number file.

Comment: It's unclear whether you want to write the result to individual files for each _pattern_ or for each _file that you search_. Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd rather for staying with grep, consider this loop

```
nums=/path/to/the/file_with_numbers_one_per_line
wdir=/path/to/dir/where/records2searchIn/located
rdir=/path/to/dir/to/put/results

for anum in $(cat ${nums}); do
 grep -nr "${anum}" ${wdir} > ${rdir}/result_file_for_${anum}; 
done
```

which does grepping for each number in list and saves individual results

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk` for that.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ptrns[$0]++;next} 
    FILENAME!="ptrns_list"{for(x in ptrns) if($0 ~ x) print $0>x}' ptrns_list infiles*.csv
```

First read all patterns to an array from where those are in *ptrns_list* file.
Then for each .csv file if in entire line `$0` one of those patterns seen `$0 ~ x` then print that line into individual file which is the same name as pattern matched.

Just pass your actual search patterns list file with `ptrns_list` and input 
.csv files with `infiles*.csv` in `ptrns_list infiles*.csv`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm hopeless at scripting, its a foreign language to me, hence my one line grep cmd.  I would need further explanation of the obvious, as to how I'd use this.

Comment: I'm still doing something wrong & I don't understand where the output files are directed to go.  This does not give me errors but no output `code` awk 'NR==FNR{ptrns[$0]++;next} 
    FILENAME!="ptrns_list"{for(x in ptns) if($0 ~ x) print $0>x}' ./ptns_list ./Aug-2017/*.csv `code`

Comment: Sorry for my typo above,  I've simplified loco & file names.  So script "awkphsearch.sh" is in its root dir, containing all mthly *.csv cdrs files & a ph numbers list file, listing numbers to be searched in individual lines - "phno-list"  & output files r to go to sub dir "results"    Pls adjust / fill in correct info to get your AWK script to achieve this.  Thanks

Comment: if your PATTERNs listed in a file called "myPattern_list" and your .csv files in a directory like `/path/to/all*.csv` then this `awk` script `awk 'NR==FNR{ptrns[$0]++;next} 
    FILENAME!="myPattern_list"{for(x in ptrns) if($0 ~ x) print $0>x}' myPattern_list /path/to/all*.csv` will process all those .csv files and produce a result in current working directory where you executed the `awk` command with multiple files which their name exactly are what you have patterns in your `myPattern_list` file.