# how to search a file for all occurances of a list in another file

Tags: files, search

Looking for advice on how to search one file for all occurances of a list in another file and output to a results file.

The source file being searched is a list of short names, FQDNS (A records and CNAME's) from a DNS server. The input file is a list of short names which I want to match any occurance. For example if the search list contains:

```
host123
```

I'd like it to find all records containing that, so for example:

```
host123.example.com
host123-idrac.example.com
host123-backup.example.com
test-cname.example.com > host123.example.com
```

I'm a bit new  to this kindof thing so although I maybe able to do this with grep I was hoping to learn a different, maybe more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Welcome to SE ! Please, tell us: **(1)** what shell you use, issuing `$ echo $SHELL` at your terminal prompt, **(2)** an example of pattern list format, **(3)** whether upper or lower case is significant (I imagine it is not, given your use case).

Comment: @alfapersius Consider adding clarifications to the text of the question, not in comments.

Comment: Exact cross-dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/43042366.  Very similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/397612/72707

Comment: thanks, answers are:

1. bash
2. pattern list is just a text file of short hostnames so example would be:

host123
host456
host789

and the file being searched is a csv with shortname and FQDN, for example:

host123, host123.example.com
host456, host456.example.com

3. case should being ignored as there is a mixture.

Answer (score 0):

I think grep its the way to go, for efficiency you can use "grep -f" which is faster that placing a for loop or something like that.
You can use awk just for fun or 2 nested for loops

```
grep -f search_list_file database_file
```

Comment: OP asked for redirecting output to a result file.

Comment: You may also want to use `-F` to use the strings in the list file as strings rather than as regular expressions. You also mention something about using `awk`, but you never say how.

Answer (score 0):

If your searched patterns are one to a line in a file, say `patterns`, the searched file is named `searched_file`, and the result is dumped in `result.out`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[tolower($0)]=1;next} {for (i in a) if(index(tolower($0),i)) print }' \
  patterns searched_file > result.out
```

Case insensitive search adapted from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43042366) by JamesBrown on stackoverflow.com. This was tested on `bash`.